# How to disable only a visual in renders and not the effect

Tags: rendering

I made a fish with swimming animation, using a plane with deform modifier.
The problem is that if I disable the plane in render, the whole animation of the fish will be disable. But if I don't disable the plane, it will be visible in the render...I tried to make transparent shading, but it makes my animation going wrong.

So is there a way to disable only the visual and not the effect?

[image: o]

Answer (score 2):

Of course there is a way.

You need to make your fish image transparent.
Not the whole image, just the grey parts.

Here is how you do it:
01) Use Photoshop, Gimp or other software to remove the fish image background.
02) Save it as a PNG.
03) Add it to Blender and set the nodes like in my example.

*Remove image background*
[image: removing background in photoshop]

*Enable transparency for your image*
[image]

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you want me to do, because I'm doing an animation, not a image.

Comment: @user78546 My mistake. I thought you are animating a plane with a texture of a fish. Or is your fish a 3D object?

Comment: Yes, it is a fish swimming in water. The plane has deform modifier and cloth in order to move like a flag, and the fish is parent to it.

Comment: Okay, I understand now.
All you have to do, is go to *Properties panel->Object->Visibility* and uncheck visibility for camera. There’s a bunch of checkboxes, try what works best for you.

Comment: What you are suggesting is another way to do what I have already tried. Enable/disable in viewport or in render :(

Comment: Hello, since I really want to help you, consider uploading your .blend file somewhere, co others could take a look. Maybe I’m reading your question wrong, and solving stuff you don’t need. :).

Comment: Here is my project : [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6736" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6736/)

Comment: @user78546 Oh, I get it now. You’re using Evee Render Engine. Switch to Cycles, and there will be waaayy more options under Object->Visibility.
And some of these options allow you to disable visibility for camera - which is what you want.
Again, you need to switch to Cycles Render Engine.

Comment: did you try to render like that?

Comment: Sorry but even in cycles, I don't see more options. If you succeed something, please tell me.