# How to make a texture transparent in Blender?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, transparency

I've been making a scene of an office. I have to put in a office chair that has a mesh, but I'm struggling with the texture as I can't make it transparent. Does anybody know how to fix this? Or where I can find a working texture for the mesh?

Attached is the model so you guys can take a closer look at it.

[image]

Many thanks, look forward to your suggestions.

Karl.

Comment: Hello. Here is a short post on how to make any texture transparent https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/156619/78972.

Comment: You're using JPG image that doesn't support transparency. Use PNG instead, and it will work :)

Comment: Technically, you can add a transparency node that will take a b/w image, using the values in a mix shader that will mix in transparency.